# How to stop debug info from printing to serial esp8266 websocketioclient

Tags: socket.io, arduino, esp8266

I'm building a project based on Socket-IO-client from here https://github.com/timum-viw/socket.io-client

I need to turn off all serial data being printed except what I send to serial. I've tried removing #define USE_SERIAL and removing or changing USE_SERIAL to use Serial1 port also edited SocketIOClient.cpp to remove debug statements in there but still getting a lot of this...

```
[WS][0][sendFrame] sending Frame Done (4506us).
[WS][0][handleWebsocketWaitFor] size: 2 cWsRXsize: 0
[readCb] n: 2 t: 597463
[WS][0][handleWebsocketWaitFor][readCb] size: 2 ok: 1
[WS][0][handleWebsocket] ------- read massage frame -------
[WS][0][handleWebsocket] fin: 1 rsv1: 0 rsv2: 0 rsv3 0  opCode: 1
[WS][0][handleWebsocket] mask: 0 payloadLen: 1
[readCb] n: 1 t: 597478
[WS][0][handleWebsocket] text: 3
```

I want to receive a websocket Message and print that to serial so arduino mega can read that serial passed to it. I don't want to have to parse all the serial being printed to find the message I actually need.

I'm using a basic nodemcu esp8266 12E module, coding with arduino ide 1.8.5. I'm sure there is something easy I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was simple and I was overlooking something. Solomons answer makes sense but I solved it right before checking Stack Overflow and seeing his post. The solution was a combination of his answer or commenting out the debug statements in the .cpp file but also needed was to go in to Arduino IDE tools menu and set DEBUG PORT to "disabled" and DEBUG LEVEL to "None". I  had already tried that before but a mistake in my code had made me think that turned off all serial communication. But revisiting that with new code produced the desired results of only printing my

```
Serial.print();
```

statements thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple actually. In socketIoClient.h you have a define like so:

`#define SOCKETIOCLIENT_DEBUG(...) Serial.print(__VA_ARGS__);`

You can change it to:

`#define SOCKETIOCLIENT_DEBUG(...) do{} while(0);`

or simply:

`#define SOCKETIOCLIENT_DEBUG(...)`

That should rid you of the debug messages but I reckon that esp8266 by itself prints some debug messages to UART too at some special events like connecting or disconnecting to an AP. You may need to follow this from espressif's API reference:

"os_install_putc1((void *)uart1_write_char) in uart_init will set os_printf to be output from UART 1, otherwise, os_printf default output from UART 0."

os_printf is used as default printing function by the OS as well as many applications. Arduino's Serial lib should use uart0 directly and not os_printf so doing the above would only rid you of the messages the OS produces.